# On-the-fly zip to browser from PHP, MySQL closes the connection within 60 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, zip, on-the-fly

- Files as BLOB in MySQL
- Connection as root to MySQL from PHP
- set_time_limit(0);ignore_user_abort(FALSE); at start of PHP Script
- Using mysql_unbuffered_query from PHP
- Getting each row and sending it to browser zipped (on-the-fly to save RAM memory and space on disk)
- Some clients with slow connections (600Kb/s - 5Mb/s)
- Getting rows, between it can pass more that 1 minute (content is send with flush())
- SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800 and SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800 before query execution
- MySQL is closing the connection exactly in 60 seconds (When the download of file to client is more that 1 minute)
- Query status in SHOW PROCESSLIST is "Writing to net" from start until it close.

What settings Can I adjust for prevent to MySQL closes the connection on inactivity on the middle of a mysql_unbuffered_query? Saving RAM Memory and disk.

Comment: Surely performing compression "on-the-fly" will use *more* RAM and disk space than performing it in advance?  Furthermore, why store files in a *relational* database management system when you have a highly optimised database for file storage in your *filesystem*?

Comment: @eggyal "on-the-fly" (file by file from MySQL -> PHP -> Browser) don't use any space on disk, the max memory use is the more big file (is fixed to < 8MB).

About store files in MySQL as BLOB and not in the filesystem, it do not depend of filesystem (no problems about file perms, eg). But this is a topic that I would not want discuss here.

Comment: MySQL uses space on disk.  If the data was pre-compressed, it would use less; likewise the RAM involved in fetching and then compressing a file will be greater.  Permissions are enforced at your application layer, not in the storage layer.

Comment: MySQL uses space on disk as filesystem. Data is not pre-compressed. No space disk is used in zip process.